# Making a class object with a variable in its name, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 60
y = 300
platform_name = "Platform"
platform_parts = 1
%s.Platform(x,y, "edge_left") % platform_name+"_"+str(platform_parts)
```

This is supposed to create a platform from my Platform class with the name Platform_1, but instead it gives a syntax error, pointing at the `%s` part. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here and how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Don't do this. Use a container, like a `dict` instead

Comment: `%s` is for string fomatting

Comment: Are you trying to make a subclass? It's unclear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class object with a variable name by using the `type` builtin.

```
>>> class Foo: pass  # Normal class declaration.

>>> Foo  # See how it's printed.
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo_1 = Foo()  # Instantiation and assignment.
>>> Foo_1
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000029B7FF5A240>
>>> name = 'Bar'  # Name in a string variable.
>>> globals()[name] = type(name, (), {})  # Dynamic class name from variable.
>>> Bar
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Bar()
<__main__.Bar object at 0x0000029B7FF5AA90>
```

You can also run code in strings using `exec`. Using `exec` is usually frowned upon because there's almost always a better way, but beginners often don't know how. But this technique is even used in the standard library e.g. in `namedtuple`.

```
>>> name = 'Baz'
>>> codestring = f'''
class {name}: pass
'''
>>> codestring
'\nclass Baz: pass\n'
>>> print(codestring)

class Baz: pass

>>> exec(codestring, globals())
>>> Baz
<class '__main__.Baz'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to assign an instance to a dynamic name,

```
globals()[platform_name+"_"+str(platform_parts)] = Platform(x,y, "edge_left")
```

Which would make the global variable named `Platform_1` with the `Platform` instance.